# How to make the camera follow the player in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey i am making a unity game called Cube-Runner. There is a cube and obstacles and you have to go between them. Not going into the game a lot but the problem is how to follow the player. I can't parent it as if i do that while the cube falls the camera will also move with the rotating cube and will make the player(At least myself) dizzy.

**Please give me a script**

*There needs to be a offset Vector3 which i can change from the inspector.*

*The offset Vector3 may work.*

*It should be written in C#.*

**NOTE: I AM NEW TO C# AND UNITY DO NOT JUDGE BY QUESTION**

Comment: If you're new to C# and Unity, you might try one of the very first Unity tutorials, called Roll a Ball. It explains how to have the camera follow the player here: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/moving-the-camera?uv=2019.4&projectId=5f158f1bedbc2a0020e51f0d#

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! As you say yourself you want `c#` ..

Comment: `Please give me a script` .. StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone implement XY for me (or tell me how to do it" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". Please make sure to take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you dont want to make the player the parent of the camera, then you can do this :

1. Create a C# script called `CameraMovement` and attach it to the camera
2. add this to `CameraMovement`

```
using UnityEngine;

class CameraMovement : MonoBehavior
{
    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void Update()
    {
        //get the players position and add it with offset, then store it to transform.position aka the cameras position
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }
}
```

3. click on the camera and look at the inspector, you should see that there is a script called `CameraMovement` and 2 fields : `player` and `offset`. assign `player` with your player (drag and drop) and offset with the relative position between your camera and the player (where the camera is with the player being the center).

and you're done, play the game and see the results

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **cinemachine** tool, it will make you camera follow smoothly to the player. You could check any tutorial on youtube but I recommend you to check the one **"Brackeys"** did. No code needed for cinemachine

Comment: What is a cinemachine

Comment: Its a tool for dynamic cameras in unity